# TFS - Shelve sets - You cannot unshelve a change to $/Business/Path/Logic because there is a conflict on this item in your workspace

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, devtools, shelveset

I wanted to transfer my work from on pc to another (at home). I checked in a shelve set on my main pc. I pulled it from my laptop fine. I then updated my code on my main pc and made another shelve set. I pulled it again on my laptop. It was taking some, so I cancelled the operation and deleted the whole directory on my laptop disk. When I tried getting the shelve set again I just get

> Multiple error occurred during the operations, the first of which is
>   displayed below. A full error list is available in the Output Window
>   You cannot unshelve a change to $/Business/Path/Logic because there is
>   a conflict on this item in your workspace

The output window lists about 100 of these:

> You cannot unshelve a change to $/Business/Path/Logic/app.config because there is
>   a conflict on this item in your workspace. You must first resolve the conflict or exclude this file when you unshelve the shelveset.

What? I just want a new copy of the latest shelve set. I tried mapping to a new path on my laptop, but same thing.

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like when you "deleted the whole directory" on your laptop source control actually picked this up as a change. If that is the case your laptop should actually show that you have changes in your "My work" area. If you do and didn't really intend to make that change just undo the checkout.

This version of VS is a little different... even if you make a change using the Explorer and not within the VS source control explorer it can pick that change up. This is normally a great thing... you can use whatever editor you like and it will count that as a change. But you have to be aware that it is going to do that so that you don't accidently make unintended changes.